# AutoMapper ignores MaxDepth when foreign key entity is of the same type

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, automapper

I am trying to get AutoMapper to only map the first level of an Entity, so I set MaxDepth(1), which works great, except for my Menu entity which has a property called ParentMenu that is also of type Menu.

**Startup.cs**

```
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services
      ...
      ...
      .AddAutoMapper(config =>
      {
        config.AddProfiles(typeof(Startup).Assembly);
        config.ForAllMaps((cfg, expr) =>
        {
           if (typeof(Entity).IsAssignableFrom(cfg.DestinationType))
           {
              expr.MaxDepth(1);
           }
        });
        config.CreateMissingTypeMaps = true;
        config.ValidateInlineMaps = false;
      });
   ...
   ...
}
```

**Menu.cs**

```
public class Menu : Entity
{
  int Id {get; set;}
  string Name {get; set;}
  int ParentMenuId {get; set;}
  Menu ParentMenu {get; set;}
  int ModuleId {get; set;}
  Module Module {get; set;}
}
```

**MenuViewModel.cs**

```
public class MenuViewModel
{
  int Id {get; set;}
  string Name {get; set;}
  int ParentMenuId {get; set;}
  string ParentMenuName {get; set;}
  int ModuleId {get; set;}
  string ModuleName {get; set;}
}
```

**MenuController.cs**

```
public IActionResult Edit(MenuViewModel viewModel)
{
  var model = EditGetModel(id); // returns the Menu Entity
  Mapper.Map(viewModel, model);
  // model.ParentMenuId is set properly
  // model.ParentMenu set to a new instance of Menu ignoring MaxDepth(1)
  // model.ModuleId is set properly
  // model.Module is properly left null
  ...
  ...
}
```

I can't figure out why MaxDepth(1) is ignored when an Entity has a property of the same type, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't seem to have anything to do with depth or recursion. It's also not clear what the exact problem is. The code you have is mapping a view model onto an entity. If I had to guess, I'd imagine the issue is that AutoMapper is creating a new `Menu` instance and replacing the existing `ParentMenu` property on your entity with that. The reason is that you're projecting `ParentMenuName`, which will map to `ParentMenu.Name` on the entity. You should ignore `ParentMenu` in the mapping:

```
CreateMap<MenuViewModel, Menu>()
    ...
    .ForMember(dest => dest.ParentMenu, opts => opts.Ignore());
```

Comment: MaxDepth(1) works as expected for the Module property, it just doesn't work when the property is of the same type and the entity being mapped.

Comment: The point is that you're not mapping anything that would result in any sort of recursion or even has relationships in the first place. Your view model is a 100% flat model, not related to anything else. Based on the code you've posted, the view model is your source, so this is just a straight-forward projection mapping.

Comment: Max depth does do what I think you think it does. It's talking about how many levels deep to map the source object. It has *nothing* to do with the destination. The view model has no levels so max depth doesn't apply here at all. As I said in my answer, a new `Menu` instance is being created because `ParentMenuName` is being projected onto `ParentMenu.Name`, and AutoMapper must instantiate `ParentMenu` to set that.

Comment: Automapper assumes that ParentMenuId should be mapped to ParentMenu.Id, the same is true for ModuleId being mapped to Module.Id; If I don't set MaxDepth(1), both ParentMenu.Id and Module.Id are set; but when MaxDepth(1) is set, Module.Id is not set because it respects the MaxDepth(1) setting, however, ParentMenu.Id is mapped when it should behave the same as the Module; There appears to be an issue when the property is of the same type. It doesn't matter if the ViewModel is flat, Automapper makes assumptions about mapping based on name; hence the use of MaxDepth(1).

Comment: No. The Id isn't mapped because there's a literal property with that name on the destination (`ParentMenuId`), so it doesn't need to project onto `ParentMenu`. There is no `ParentMenuName` property, so it projects to `ParentMenu.Name`. Max depth has nothing to do with this.

Comment: How do you explain the behavior of the Module property? The Module entity also has an Id property and a Name property; if what your saying is true, then they should both exhibit the same behavior, but they don't; Module respects the setting, ParentMenu does not.

Comment: How should I know? I don't have visibility into all that, nor your actual AutoMapper profile(s). It's not max depth, though, is what I'm saying. That's 100% about how deep to go on the *source*. It has nothing to do with the destination.

Comment: Do you have a citation saying that the MaxDepth is for the source? It's working as I expect in all other cases and removing it causes all of those cases to map the relation properties.

Comment: My apologies, I checked the AutoMapper source and it appears that you are right... Although I can't explain the current mapping behavior...

Is there no generic way to tell AutoMapper to only map the first level of the destination?

Comment: It is only mapping the first level. Your view model is only one level. You need to ignore the destination member as I said in my answer.

Comment: I need a generic way to ignore them though, I am using dynamics for the reverse mapping to prevent under posting... I probably just need ditch the idea of reverse mapping all together.

Comment: I don't know of a generic way, since it's dependent on the property names. For reference, this is what's happening: http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Reverse-Mapping-and-Unflattening.html. the docs have other ways to prevent it, but all require config for the type(s). While AutoMapper is low config, it's not no config in anything but the most simple of scenarios.